# '70s-'80s cartoon featuring a man swinging on vines through a cave to get an egg

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember seeing this as a child and for some reason it stuck with me because it was frightening. I think what was frightening about it was that the man got the egg but the monster caught up with him, which is really unusual for a cartoon.

So what I remember is a clip of a guy who enters a cave, and you see the side view of the cave. The man has to swing on some vines for whatever reason, and his target is apparently an egg that he actually is able to grab. However, there was some sort of humanoid monster in the cave with him and it caught up with him and pulled him down. I think the clip ended after that. Not sure what this was from but would be cool thing to find out because I've always wondered if there was more to the story!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, can you describe the appearance of the man or the monster at all?

Comment: I wish I could but I was probably 4-5 at the time. I'd say roughly 88-89. I've seen some other people link to the Masters of Time, it does seem like this style of animation and it definitely has a similar vibe to it but I scrolled through the whole movie and didn't see any scene like it.

Comment: I wonder if this is a memory of one of the 1967 *Spider-Man* episodes? There's plenty of 'cave' scenes and side views, definitely a guy swinging from a rope, and humanoid monsters a-plenty (e.g., see the episodes about the Mole Men, the time machine to 3 million BC)

Comment: Nah wasn't that, I looked it up. It was grittier than Spiderman, kind of like Heavy Metal or even like the Masters of Time. The view of the cave was just like a side-scroller video game, but with the gritty cartoon graphics. The whole clip didn't last very long, and it wasn't a part of a major show it was more like a quick commercial that they showed at a commercial break for another cartoon I was probably watching. Also, Spiderman is very distinct and I would've remembered the red and blue. This guy was more neutral colors from what I recall.

Comment: sounds like the 1970s Tarzan cartoon series. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RP4k_SDHR44

Comment: @Pete yeah I was gonna say Tarzan

Comment: Sounds like a possibility, but the monster did seem more like a Heavy Metal-ish type of character. Humanoid but kind of scary looking, like a reptilian or something. I can't seem to find more episodes of this Tarzan series.

Comment: This might be so obscure that we may never figure it out. I'm 37 now and the memory of it has stuck with me for that long.